# TableTools only exporting single header row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the [DataTables jquery plugin](http://datatables.net/)

I have a DataTable that has multi-row table header with colspan. 
Something like:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Level 1</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Level 1 - Item 1</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Level 1 - Item 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Level 2</th>
    <th>Level 2 - Item 1a</th>
    <th>Level 2 - Item 1b</th>
    <th>Level 2 - Item 2a</th>
    <th>Level 2 - Item 2b</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

However when I use the TableTools plugin to export then except for the "Print" option all the rest (Excel, CSV, Pdf etc) only has the "Level 2" header row and not the Level 1.

Any suggestions on how to get it to export also Level 1?

Comment: The same thing happenes when You have multi-row footer. I've wrote to Allan (DataTables creator) asking about these feature. I'll let You know when this will be supported :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export level1 also to excel, there is an alternative way:

Replace rowspan/colspan with empty cells like:

```
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Level 1</th>
        <th>Level 1 - Item 1</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Level 1 - Item 2</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Level 2</th>
        <th>Level 2 - Item 1a</th>
        <th>Level 2 - Item 1b</th>
        <th>Level 2 - Item 2a</th>
        <th>Level 2 - Item 2b</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

Then as suggested by `@misiu` above, Edit TableTools.js.
Find `_fnGetDataTablesData` and inside it change this:

```
if (oConfig.bHeader) { ... }
```

with this as:

```
if (oConfig.bHeader) {
    //another loop
    for (i = 0, rowCount = dt.nTHead.rows.length; i < rowCount; i++) {
        aRow = []; //clear row data
        for (j = 0, iLen = dt.aoColumns.length; j < iLen; j++) {
            if (aColumnsInc[j] && dt.nTHead.rows[i].children[j] !== null) {
                sLoopData = dt.nTHead.rows[i].children[j].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, " ")
                    .replace(/<.*?>/g, "")
                    .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                sLoopData = this._fnHtmlDecode(sLoopData);
                aRow.push(this._fnBoundData(sLoopData, oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex));
            } else {
                aRow.push(this._fnBoundData("", oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex)); //I'm not shure of this!!
            }
        }
        aData.push(aRow.join(oConfig.sFieldSeperator));
    }
}
```

This will copy/export complex headers to csv/excel. Although empty table cells will remain empty in excel and will not be merged. You can manually merge them.

Though not an ideal solution, this worked perfectly for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

Edit TableTools.js.
Find `_fnGetDataTablesData` and inside it change this:

```
if (oConfig.bHeader) {
    aRow = [];

    for (i = 0, iLen = dt.aoColumns.length; i < iLen; i++) {
        if (aColumnsInc[i]) {
            sLoopData = dt.aoColumns[i].sTitle.replace(/\n/g, " ")
                .replace(/<.*?>/g, "")
                .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            sLoopData = this._fnHtmlDecode(sLoopData);

            aRow.push(this._fnBoundData(sLoopData, oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex));
        }
    }

    aData.push(aRow.join(oConfig.sFieldSeperator));
}
```

to this:

```
if (oConfig.bHeader) {

    //another loop
    for (i = 0, rowCount = dt.nTHead.rows.length; i < rowCount; i++) {
        aRow = []; //clear row data
        for (j = 0, iLen = dt.aoColumns.length; j < iLen; j++) {
            if (aColumnsInc[j] && dt.nTHead.rows[i].children[j] !== null) {
                sLoopData = dt.nTHead.rows[i].children[j].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, " ")
                    .replace(/<.*?>/g, "")
                    .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                sLoopData = this._fnHtmlDecode(sLoopData);
                aRow.push(this._fnBoundData(sLoopData, oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex));
            } else {
                aRow.push(this._fnBoundData("", oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex)); //I'm not shure of this!!
            }
        }
        aData.push(aRow.join(oConfig.sFieldSeperator));
    }
}
```

I can't test this roght now, so give this a try.
I'll update my answer when I get better solution from Allan.

Comment: @ZiedRebhi ?? I don't understand Your comment. I have that part is my answer. Is it wrong?

Comment: is the for loop format correct !! there is 4 params

Comment: @ZiedRebhi fixed. Good eye :)

Comment: Could I ask where's this method exists please `_fnGetDataTablesData` because I have no file with the name `TableTools.js`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( oConfig.bHeader )
    {
        //-1 because we don't want the last row header
        for (i=0; i<dt.nTHead.rows.length-1; i++)
        {
            //wrap jquery object
            $(dt.nTHead.rows[i]).find('th').each(function(){
           var th = $(this);
           sData += th.text().replace(/\n/g," ").replace( /<.*?>/g, "" ).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

           var colspan = th.attr('colspan');
           if (!colspan) colspan = 1; //default colspan is 1

           //only the first colspan have the label, other colspans are empty text, we can't implement cell mergin in csv file
           for (j=0; j<colspan; j++)
           {
                 sData += oConfig.sFieldSeperator;
           }
        });

        sData += sNewline;
        }

        for ( i=0, iLen=dt.aoColumns.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
        {
            if ( aColumnsInc[i] )
            {
                sLoopData = dt.aoColumns[i].sTitle.replace(/\n/g," ").replace( /<.*?>/g, "" ).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                sLoopData = this._fnHtmlDecode( sLoopData );

                sData += this._fnBoundData( sLoopData, oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex ) +
                    oConfig.sFieldSeperator;
            }
        }
        sData = sData.slice( 0, oConfig.sFieldSeperator.length*-1 );
        sData += sNewline;
    }
```

Comment: Could I ask in which file this method exists please` _fnGetDataTablesData`

Comment: It's from the TableTools code dated back in 2012. You could try to scan for file with your code editor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22592/export-multiple-row-headers
With this piece of code, you will be able to export all the cells from the header and the colspan and rowspans will be converted in empty cells :)